# Retrofit how to get a Json inside a Json to a string using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

How to return String data from the json inside a json.
One is a check to see if there is data. a 201 response should then lead to the data being turned into a string.

I have tried to the following but it does not work.  What have I got wrong.  Can anyone explain to me so I can learn this?

//the method I call on button press.
PhpResponse and getCervicalROM are the Model classes listed below.  I try to Toast to make sure I am getting the String variable data.  But nothing comes up.

---

```
 public void downloadromdata() {
    Call <PhpResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getAPIService().getCervicalROM(ID);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<PhpResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PhpResponse> call, Response<PhpResponse> response) {

            if(response.code() == 201)
            {
            PhpResponse phpResponse = response.body();
            RACERVICALROT = phpResponse.getUser().getRACERVICALROT();
            LACERVICALROT = phpResponse.getUser().getLACERVICALROT();
                Toast.makeText(cervicaltest.this, RACERVICALROT + "&" + LACERVICALROT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(response.code() == 422){
                Toast.makeText(cervicaltest.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PhpResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

---

getCervicalROM model

```
 public class getCervicalROM {

private String RACERVICALROT, LACERVICALROT;

public getCervicalROM(String RACERVICALROT, String LACERVICALROT) {
    this.RACERVICALROT = RACERVICALROT;
    this.LACERVICALROT = LACERVICALROT;
}
public String getRACERVICALROT() {
    return RACERVICALROT;
}
public String getLACERVICALROT() {
    return LACERVICALROT;
}
```

}

---

Phpresponse Model

```
 public class PhpResponse {

private boolean error;
private String message;
private getCervicalROM user;

public PhpResponse(boolean error, String message, getCervicalROM user) {
    this.error = error;
    this.message = message;
    this.user = user;
}

public boolean isError() {
    return error;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public getCervicalROM getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

}

---

APIService

```
  @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("getCervicalROM")
 Call<PhpResponse> getCervicalROM (@Field("ID") String ID);
```

---

getCervicalROM is also name of index call.  The PHP Slim Returns data in postman so this last stuff is most likely fine.

```
 $app->post('/getCervicalROM', function(Request $request, Response $response) 
{

 if(!haveEmptyParameters(array('ID'), $response)){
    $request_data = $request->getParsedBody(); 
    $ID = $request_data['ID'];

 $db = new spinalromdbupload; 
 $result = $db->ptexists($ID);

if($result == DATA_FOUND){
 $user = $db->getCervicalROM($ID);

$response_data = array();

 $response_data['error'] = false; 
 $response_data['message'] = 'Data Aquired';
 $response_data['user'] = $user; 

 $response->write(json_encode($response_data));  
 return $response
->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
->withStatus(200);  

 } else if ($result == DATA_NOT_FOUND){
 $response_data = array();
        $response_data['error']=true; 
        $response_data['message'] = 'No ROM data entered for this pt';
        $response->write(json_encode($response_data));
        return $response
            ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
            ->withStatus(422);   
 }}
  return $response
    ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    ->withStatus(422);  
 });
```

---

the php file

```
  public function getCervicalROM($ID){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT RACERVICALROT, LACERVICALROT FROM 
  spinalromdb WHERE ID = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $ID);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($RACERVICALROT, $LACERVICALROT);
        $stmt->fetch(); 
        $user = array(); 
        $user['RACERVICALROT'] = $RACERVICALROT; 
        $user['LACERVICALROT'] = $LACERVICALROT; 
        return $user; 
    }

     private function isIDExist($ID){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT ID FROM spinalromdb WHERE ID = 
 ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $ID);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0;  
    }
```

Comment: Add log for your code. Why do you set status code 200 on response but trying to get body when status code is 201?

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my error.  the code status was off.  To any future reader if you change that status this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide default constructors for your model classes if you add constructurs with parameters.

In `PhpResponse` class, add:

```
public PhpResponse() {}
```

In `getCervicalROM` class, add:

```
public getCervicalROM() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

changed code status and code above works fine.  In the PHP index file it should be 201 not 200.